# VBA to view sheet as PDF fails if a version of Adobe is currently open

Tags: excel, pdf, vba

I wrote the following function to view a spreadsheet as a PDF on the click of an option button.

```
    Public Function RunPDFReport(CellRange As String) As String


Application.ScreenUpdating = False

refPositionDetails.Range("O2").Value = dsbDashboard.Range(CellRange).Value

    dsbDashboard.Unprotect

     On Error GoTo ErrHandler:

        With refPositionDetails

        .Visible = xlSheetVisible
        .ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
                                IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
                                OpenAfterPublish:=True, from:=1, To:=3

        .Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

                dsbDashboard.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
                dsbDashboard.Activate

             End

ErrHandler:

        MsgBox "Report Canceled", vbCritical


                         End With


End Function
```

This works fine, it does everyithng is supposed to do. Except that if I have a earlier copy of the PDF currently opened, the procedure goes straight to my error handler. It should be able to still open the new PDF and override the old one or open as a new copy.

Did I miss something?

Comment: You cannot overwrite a file that has been locked by Acrobar Reader for viewing, period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot, if it is currently opened... but I do not see a filename location in your code.
To make this work you would need to loop through the names and once successfully reach a name you exit the function... So maybe this will help?

```
name = [whatever you want the names tobe pulled from]
Number_of_Pdfs_you_should_close = 0

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    "C:\Users\tpike\Documents\" & name & ".pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:= _
    True


Number_of_PDFs_you_should_close = Number_of_PDFs_you_should_close + 1 
name = name + "(" & Number_of_Pdfs_you_should_close & ")"
```